# Error en calcular productoria matriz en C

Tags: c

la consigna es la siguiente:
Programe una funcion que reciba una matriz de enteros, de m filas por n
columnas como entrada. la funcion debe retornar la productoria de los elementos de la matriz

tengo un problema en la siguiente función para calcular productoria de una matriz en C:

```
int multiplicar(int mat[2][2]){
    int resultado;
    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            resultado = 0;
            {
                resultado += mat[i][j] * mat[j][i];

            }
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

yo lo probe con los numeros 1 2 3 4 el resultado correcto es 24 pero a mi me devuelve 16 si alguien sabe donde esta mi error.

Comment: Al contrario! tú dinos por qué dices que hay un error

Comment: al probarlo la funcion me devuelve este numero 6422048 y la matriz es de 3*4 con estos numeros 1234

Comment: Estás trabajando con una matriz no cuadrada pero cruzas los índices como si existieran todas las posiciones. Por ejemplo, con i=2, j=3, sumas al resultado `mat[3][4]*mat[4][3]`... y pues, `mat[4][3]` no existe, así que ni idea qué habrá en esa posición de memoria :P

Comment: Esa función debería recibir dos matrices. Una de 3x4 y otra de 4x3

Comment: ahi agregue la consigna sobre la cual hay que trabajar en una sola matriz.

Comment: No se entiende porque esta mal lo que decis que esta mal.. tampoco se entiende que estas tratando de hacer.. y lo que menos entiendo, es como esperas que de un resultado cuando tu return devuelve una posicion de la matriz que no existe.. por que ese i y ese j no existen...

Comment: lo que tengo que hacer es una funcion que reciba una matriz de enteros, de m filas por n columnas como entrada. la funcion debe retornar la productoria de los elementos de la matriz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres el producto de todos los elementos de la matriz, tienes que hacer una multiplicación.

- Con `resultado = 0` estás restableciendo a 0 el producto en todo momento. No se supone que hagas eso.
- Con `resultado += mat[i][j] * mat[j][i]` estás sumando. Quieres un producto, no una suma.

El código debería verse así:

```
int multiplicar(int mat[2][2]){
    int resultado = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            resultado *= mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Nota que `resultado` se inicia en 1 porque es el elemento neutro de la suma.